# Problem using for loop in function, trying to return a tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, tuples, return

> Create a new function named process_data() that takes one argument:
> data, a list or tuple of numbers.
> Use a for loop to loop through the data and return a tuple containing the follow data points in-order:
>
> - The total sum of the data
> - The average of the data with floating point precision
>
> Run the function as shown below
>
> ```
> process_data([1, 2, 3])
> (6, 2.0)
> ```

```
data = [1,2,3,4,5]
def process_data(data):
    for data return(sum)
process_data([1,2,3])
```

I'm not sure how to calculate average, but in the meantime I tried using the `sum` function to no avail. I'm getting a syntax error at `return`.

Comment: Could you show your code? People will be able to offer better advice if they can read your code directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `sum()` and `len()`

```
def process_data(data=[1,2,3,4,5]):
    return (sum(data), sum(data)/len(data))
```

This will have a default value for the function = `[1,2,3,4,5]`

```
process_data([1, 2, 3])
>>>(6, 2.0)
```

As long as your input is a list of integers, the output will be what you want.

In case there is any float number input and you want to round up the values to, for instance, 2 decimal places:

```
def process_data(data=[1,2,3,4,5]):
    return (round(sum(data),2), round(sum(data)/len(data),2))
```

Result:

```
process_data([1.2,2.08,3.19])
>>>(6.47, 2.16)
```